# I have a bug in my jquery outcome

Tags: javascript, jquery

My website is http://www.grozav.com

At the portfolio part, you can see the div containing the category name (eg. Photomanipulation) is canceling the action of the thumbnail hover state, even though it is included in the same anchor tag.

Javascript code:

```
function thumbnail(param1){
    $('#'+param1+'-thumb img').mouseover(function() {
        $('#'+param1+'-thumb .color').hide().stop().fadeTo(500,'1');
    })  
    $('#'+param1+'-thumb img').mouseout(function() {
        $('#'+param1+'-thumb .color').stop().fadeTo(500,'0');
    })                  
};

thumbnail('dubstep');
```

Thumbnail DIV structure:

```
<div class="thumb" id="dubstep-thumb" >
    <a class="ajax" href="gallery/dubstep.html">
        <p class="work-type">PHOTOMANIPULATION</p>
        <img src="images/thumbs/dubstep-bwthumb.jpg" alt="" width="300" height="169"/>
        <img src="images/thumbs/dubstep-thumb.jpg" alt="" width="300" height="169" class="color"/>
    </a>
</div>
```

CSS, if it's of any use:

```css
.thumb {
    float:left;
    width:300px;
    height:169px;
    position:relative; 
    margin-right:10px;
    margin-top:10px;
    overflow:hidden;
    z-index:1;
}
.thumb img {
    position:absolute;
    width:300px;    
    height:169px;
}
.thumb .color {
    display:none;    
}
.work-type { 
    background:url('../images/transparent.png') repeat; 
    position:absolute; 
    z-index:1;
    width:288px; 
    height:20px; 
    margin-top:141px;
    margin-left:1px;
}
.work-type {
    font-family:arial; 
    color:#a0a0a0; 
    font-size:10px; 
    text-align:right; 
    padding-top:7px; 
    padding-right:10px;
}
```

Thank you in advance for the help!

Comment: Include the code where you attach the events.

Comment: Thank you! Glad you like it. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing the selector in each event to:

```
$('#' + param1 + '-thumb')...
```

Also, you could combine the `mouseover` and `mouseout` event handlers into one using the `hover()` method, like this:

```
$('#'+param1+'-thumb').hover(
    function() {
        $('#'+param1+'-thumb .color').hide().stop().fadeTo(500,'1');
    },
    function() {
        $('#'+param1+'-thumb .color').stop().fadeTo(500,'0');
    }
) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are applying the event on the `img` tags and not the `a`. Change it like this:

```
function thumbnail(param1){
    $('#'+param1+'-thumb a').mouseover(function() {
        $('#'+param1+'-thumb .color').hide().stop().fadeTo(500,'1');
    })  
    $('#'+param1+'-thumb a').mouseout(function() {
        $('#'+param1+'-thumb .color').stop().fadeTo(500,'0');
    })                  
};
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, I tried this method as well. It was activating itself twice (once on the image and once on the description div)